# python - latexmk: error: no such option: -d

Tags: python, pdf, tex, latexmk

I am getting an error when I want to run a python script:

The error is following one:

[image]

The code is given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
code_dir = "code"
title = "Stanford ACM-ICPC Team Notebook"

def get_sections():
    sections = []
    section_name = None
    with open('contents.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if '#' in line: line = line[:line.find('#')]
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) == 0: continue
            if line[0] == '[':
                section_name = line[1:-1]
                subsections = []
                if section_name is not None:
                    sections.append((section_name, subsections))
            else:
                tmp = line.split('\t', 1)
                if len(tmp) == 1:
                    raise ValueError('Subsection parse error: %s' % line)
                filename = tmp[0]
                subsection_name = tmp[1]
                if subsection_name is None:
                    raise ValueError('Subsection given without section')
                subsections.append((filename, subsection_name))
    return sections

def get_style(filename):
    ext = filename.lower().split('.')[-1]
    if ext in ['c', 'cc', 'cpp']:
        return 'cpp'
    elif ext in ['java']:
        return 'java'
    elif ext in ['py']:
        return 'py'
    else:
        return 'txt'

# TODO: check if this is everything we need
def texify(s):
    #s = s.replace('\'', '\\\'')
    #s = s.replace('\"', '\\\"')
    return s

def get_tex(sections):
    tex = ''
    for (section_name, subsections) in sections:
        tex += '\\section{%s}\n' % texify(section_name)
        for (filename, subsection_name) in subsections:
            tex += '\\subsection{%s}\n' % texify(subsection_name)
            tex += '\\raggedbottom\\lstinputlisting[style=%s]{%s/%s}\n' % (get_style(filename), code_dir, filename)
            tex += '\\hrulefill\n'
        tex += '\n'
    return tex

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sections = get_sections()
    tex = get_tex(sections)
    with open('contents.tex', 'w') as f:
        f.write(tex)
    latexmk_options = ["latexmk", "-pdf", "notebook.tex"]
    subprocess.call(latexmk_options)
```

I have already tried to install latexmk, But didn't succeed.
Can you help me about the detailed instruction of installation latexmk. I have already googled much. And for copyright thats not even my code. Its a code from [stanford acm](https://github.com/jaehyunp/stanfordacm) to make their own. Now I want to use to make my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `latexmk` is accessible from your command line. You can check this by typing `latexmk -version` from your command line. If it is not accessible from command line then you need to add the `latexmk` path to environment variable.

If `latexmk` is not installed  follow this [link](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/support/latexmk/INSTALL) to properly install the `latexmk`.

I think following these steps might fix your problem.